# Looking for a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I was just wondering if there exists a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. I started thinking about this due to the following problem:

Suppose there exists a homeomorphism between $X$ and a subspace of $Y$ and another homeomorphism between $Y$ and a subspace of $X$. Does it follow that $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic?

It doesn't seem intuitive to me that it does, so I'm trying to find a counterexample (e.g. we take $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ for $X$ and $Y$).

So my question is if the implication holds and if it does not, whether there exists a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ and a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not homeomorphic to any subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, by the invariance of domain. It's nontrivial to prove that, though.

Comment: OK, thanks. Could someone tell me if the implication holds then and if not, provide a counterexample? No need to prove it, I want to do that myself. I just don't wanna attempt to prove something that isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a counterexample, take an open interval $\Bbb{R}$ and a closed inverval in $\Bbb{R}$.

For example, take $[0,3]$ and $(0,3)$. $[0,3]\cong[1,2]\subset(0,3)$ and $(0,3)\cong(1,2)\subset[0,3]$, but $[0,3]\not\cong(0,3)$.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb R^2$ has the property that after removing any point, it is still connected.  No infinite subset of $\mathbb R$ has that property.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ were homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then $A$ is connected and thus must equal some non-trivial interval in $ I \subset \mathbb{R}$. For almost all points $p$ of $I$, $I \setminus \{p\}$ is disconnected, but $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{q\}$ is always connected...

Answer (score 0):

No, like Daniel said you can't because of invariance of domain. So your counterexample for the general problem doesn't work, but this one does: in the plane, draw a circle of radium 1/2 centred at $(n,0)$ for every $n\in \mathbb N$, and call this space $X$. Then, erase from $X$ all points with negative abscissa, and call this new space $Y$. It's easy to see that you can put $X$ and $Y$ one in the other, but they are not  homeomorphic: you can split $Y$ in three components erasing only one point, but you can't do the same with $X$.